# Which Drupal 7 database table is file uploaded to?

Tags: database, file, upload, drupal-7, blob

I am working on drupal 7 which has content type that has a filed "**file**" and the file is uploaded  to **mysql database**.

I would like to find the table where the file is stored as binary **BLOB** type.
Know the node ID.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have something special installed that I'm not familiar with, the files themselves aren't stored as binaries/serialized/etc in the DB. The file table (or is it the filr_managed table? I apologize, I'm on my phone and will try to answer more fully when I sit down at a computer) just stores things like the file id (fid) and the path to the file.

As I understand it, storing the files themselves, fully in the DB would lead to some pretty heavy/intense DB call times.

I'm not sure if this is a reason why you expect it to be in the DB, but if you are looking for the files to be accessible following their nodes access, you'll want to look into setting up private file storage outside of the Drupal root directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a default configuration, you will find your files in the filesystem, in the following subdirectory of your Drupal installation :

`drupal/sites/default/files`

If you want to store all the file in the DB, tou can by using a hook on saving file, but it is not recommended for performance reason. Better to acces a file by URL than download it from database.